# Why does adding function as in A3 or removing function as in B3 cause errors?

Tags: javascript

Why does adding `function` as in `A3` or removing `function` as in `B3` cause errors?

#### Version A1

```js
let x = {
    func: function () {
        console.log(`Hi`);
    }
}
```

#### Version A2

```js
let x = {
    func() {
        console.log(`Hi`);
    }
}
```

#### Version A3 (Not Working)

```js
let x = {
    function func() {
        console.log(`Hi`);
   }
}
```

#### Version B1

```js
let func = function () {
    console.log(`Hi`);
}
```

#### Version B2

```js
function func() {
    console.log(`Hi`);
}
```

#### Version B3 (Not Working)

```js
func() {
    console.log(`Hi`);
}
```

Comment: Because they're not correct syntax. Object literals don't use the same syntax as statements.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you for answering. By the way, are `B1` and `B2` identical?

Comment: They're not identical with regard to scoping or hoisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the syntax and grammar defined for JavaScript does not provide for the validity of the code you have written.

Simply put, the code is invalid.